# Hbase reverse scan showing different result, not matching with the result I get from forward scan

Tags: hbase

Reverse scan yielding me less row count than what is expected.
Is there any explanation on this behaviour? How to get all rows in reverse scan?

Hbase version: 2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78 
9 rs cluster, with avg ~60 regions/rs. The table 'xxx' has 40 regions equally distributed among rs.

```
scan 'xxx', {LIMIT => 1000, STARTROW=>"6cfc>YDTFISIT1>000036", STOPROW=>"6cfc>YDTFISIT1>000037"}


scan 'xxx', {LIMIT => 1000, STARTROW=>"6cfc>YDTFISIT1>000037", STOPROW=>"6cfc>YDTFISIT1>000036", REVERSED=>true}
```

When tried forward scan, I got 199 rows. But on reverse scan i got only 23 rows.

[FORWARD SCAN RESULT](https://gist.github.com/chandurup/a5e01e8e2ad526dffa8aa08718646126)

[REVERSE SCAN RESULT](https://gist.github.com/chandurup/e42fa026098e4f04f89f7c8d110b7e64)

Comment: You may be hitting a bug https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-21621

Comment: @mazaneicha Perfect thanks.